# Excel Formula using substitute function to replace quotation marks

Tags: ms-office

Substitute formula is `substitute(cell to focus on, text to replace, text that replaces it)`. 2nd and 3rd inputs need to be in quotations it seems to get the function to work.

So how would you substitute a single quotation mark in a cell.

None of the following work:

```
=substitute(A1,""","%22C")
=substitute(A1,&char(32), "%22C")
=substitute(A1,"&char(32)","%22C")
=substitute(A1,"\"","%22C")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This question is a "I'm using mac:office 2011 and have a problem with an Excel formula" away from being perfectly on topic. And it got an valid answer already. I don't see a reason to close or migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34),"%22C")
```

[image]

`&` is for concatenation, but you're not concatenating, so it should be omitted.
`CHAR(34)`, not 32, is the double quote character.

Comment: Sorry George; upvote for the answer but a close vote for the question :/

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't notice this was about Excel and not Numbers; my answer was for Numbers, just so happens it works exactly the same in Excel too! Fair point, I've voted for closure for migration to Super User.

Comment: I think it would be a better fit there, for sure. Lots of Excel questions on there.

Comment: Also, =substitute(A1,"""","%22C")

"""" backs out a single ".